# Uniqueness of a symbol in a place-value system

Tags: elementary-number-theory, formal-languages

I'm looking for a proof of the following hypothesis:

Given the tuple $(\{a_0, ..., a_{n-1}\},++)$, where $a_i, i = 1 ... n-1 \in \mathbb{N}$ represent arbitrary, pairwise different symbols and $++$ is an increment operator, such that

$$
\begin{array}{l}
++(a_{i_{k-1}}a_{i_{k-2}}...a_{i_1}a_{i_0}) = 
\begin{cases}
++(a_{i_{k-1}}a_{i_{k-2}}...a_{i_1})a_0 \quad \text{if } i_0 = n-1\\
a_{i_{k-1}}a_{i_{k-2}}...a_{i_1}a_{i_0+1} \quad \text{else},
\end{cases} \\
++(a_i) = a_{i+1}, \quad i < n-1
\end{array}
$$

where $a_ia_j$ is the concatenation of two symbols. Two objects $a_{i_{k-1}}a_{i_{k-2}}...a_{i_0}$ and $a_{j_{k-1}}a_{j_{k-2}}...a_{j_0}$, made up from concatenated symbols, are considered different, if $a_{i_l} \neq a_{j_l}$ for at least one $l \in \{0,...,k-1\}$.

Show that, after $p$ times repeated incrementation, starting from $\underbrace{a_0a_0...a_0}_m$, the concatenated object

$$(++)^p(a_0a_0...a_0), \quad 1 \le p < n^m$$

differs from every of its predecessors.

Comment: What is ${+\!+}(a_na_n)$? According to your rule it should be $a_{n+1}a_1$, but there is no $a_{n+1}$.

Comment: can you pleeease start indexing at $0$ arrrrrgh

Comment: And you don't seem to have any rule at all that gives meaning to ${+\!+}^p(a_1a_1\ldots a_1)$ when there are more (or less) than two $a_1$s.

Comment: @HenningMakholm - Hope my edit made it a consistent question.

Answer (score 0):

*Proof by induction*. Applying the $++$-operator $n^k$-times increments index $i_k$. This holds for $k=0$ from the definition of $++$.

($k \rightarrow k+1$): From the hypothesis, we have that incrementing $i_k$ $n$-times requires $\underbrace{n^k + ... + n^k}_n = n \cdot n^k = n^{k+1}$ incrementations. Where the definition of the incrementation operator for $i_k = i_{k-1} = ... = i_0 = n-1$ requires that

$$++(a_{i_{m-1}}a_{i_{m-2}}...a_{i_{k+1}})a_{n-1}...a_{n-1} = a_{i_{m-1}}a_{i_{m-2}}...a_{i_{k+1}+1}a_0...a_0,$$

which represents the $n^{(k+1)\text{st}}$ incrementation operation.

Since $a_{i_k+1} \neq a_{i_k} $ for $i_k < n-1$ from the definition of $a_i$, the concatenated object $a_{i_{m-1}}a_{i_{m-2}}...a_{i_k+1}...a_{i_0}$ differs from every of its predecessors.

*Remark:* The $n^m$-th incrementation operation cannot be applied due to overflow resulting in a total of $(n^m-1)+1 = n^m$ unique concatenated objects.